# Batch if not error

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem using `if not` in batch. I'm creating a little game and I have added an inventory system, to carry things around. Basically, at the moment I have 10 inventory slots, and when I view my inventory I want to only see a slot in the inventory if it has an item in it. By default, I have all the inventory slots set to Empty (I know there is probably a simpler way to do this, if there is please let me know) and this block follows;

```
:inventory
cls
if not %slotone%==Empty echo %slotone%
if not %slottwo%==Empty echo %slottwo%
if not %slotthree%==Empty echo %slotthree%
if not %slotfour%==Empty echo %slotfour%
if not %slotfive%==Empty echo %slotfive%
if not %slotsix%==Empty echo %slotsix%
if not %slotseven%==Empty echo %slotseven%
if not %sloteight%==Empty echo %sloteight%
if not %slotnine%==Empty echo %slotnine%
if not %slotten%==Empty echo %slotten%
pause
goto %invback%
```

This returns an error, and I'm not sure why. Any help?

Comment: The exact error text would help narrow down the problem.  But from just looking, I think you need to quote your strings: `if "%slotone%" NEQ "Empty" echo %slotone%`

Comment: Just saying if you are going through so much effort to make a game in batch, you might as well learn python and do it well (and make it easier for you)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a case insensitive way of comparing text using `if not` and `/i` and which protects against spaces, null strings, and poison characters.

```
if /i not "%slotone%"=="Empty" echo %slotone%
```